# ML curve's outliers clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, fft, k-means

I'm working on a project where I need to find and sort out unusual data points in a graph that shows voltage fluctuation.
[image: graph]
I have csv file with sample points (10K datapoints) that represent the graph. So I do not need convert graph to data point with fft.

But here's where I'm stuck: I'm having trouble to cluster the outliers data. I assume that data points classification should use context and take in account the neighbor data points.  But I can’t manage how that could be done by in order to detect whole peak.
I have no idea how to make K-means to consider marked peak as separate and whole object. Or how to prepare data before try to put them in cluster algorithm.

I'd really appreciate any advice or tips you might have.